# Model assumptions and diagnostics for proportional hazard regression model with frailty in R

Tags: r, cox-model, assumptions, diagnostic, frailty

I am wondering are there any assumptions that must be met in the proportional hazard regression model with frailty? I remember that in regular proportional hazard model without frailty all variables need to significant in log-rank test which means that the survival curves for each variable differ significantly and are proportional.

Moreover I was thinking about model diagnostics. Is Schoenfeld test appropriate for model with frailties? Also do scored Schoenfeld's residuals (or martingale residuals) are a good measure of model fit like in model without frailty?

Maybe there are no assumptions and diagnostics for this kind of model?

And quick question about model conclusions. Below is syntax of a model fit and I am curious about p-value next to frailty. It is higher than 0.05. Does it mean there is no significant frailty in the data? Also `Variance of random effect= 0.493`. Does it stand for frailty or opposite that the frailty model is inappropriate?

Thanks for any help!

```
Call:
coxph(formula = Surv(time, inf) ~ age + sex + frailty(patient, 
    dist = "gaus") + as.factor(type), data = kidneyExt)

                          coef     se(coef) se2    Chisq DF   p      
age                        0.00489 0.015    0.0106  0.11  1.0 0.74000
sex                       -1.69728 0.461    0.3617 13.55  1.0 0.00023
frailty(patient, dist = "                          17.89 12.1 0.12000
as.factor(type)1           0.21308 0.516    0.3828  0.17  1.0 0.68000
as.factor(type)2          -1.31617 0.781    0.5817  2.84  1.0 0.09200
as.factor(type)3          -0.17986 0.545    0.3927  0.11  1.0 0.74000

Iterations: 7 outer, 42 Newton-Raphson
     Variance of random effect= 0.493 
Degrees of freedom for terms=  0.5  0.6 12.1  1.7 
Likelihood ratio test=47.5  on 14.9 df, p=2.82e-05  n= 76
```